# Youtube embedded iframe and preloadResponse error

Tags: youtube

I have an embedded iframe for youtube video using https://www.youtube.com/embed/video id. However, when I have this on my page I get the following error.
[image]

And when I remove the youtube iframe the error goes away.

What is this this error?

How do I get rid of it?